# QSampler: "Could not start server. Sorry."

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, midi

Running Bionic Beaver (18.04) release of Lubuntu.  I've installed `qsampler`, but when I start it up it displays

```
Server is starting...
linuxsampler
Could not start server.  Sorry.
Server was stopped with exit status 0.
```

`find / -mount -iname '*linuxsampler*'` doesn't yield any results.

`aptitude search ~dlinuxsampler` doesn't show any packages which appear to install `linuxsampler`.

Do I need to install another package in order to use `qsampler`?  If so, where do I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`linuxsampler` is [not packaged for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linuxsampler). This appears to be because of the [exception](https://www.linuxsampler.org/downloads.html) in its GPL licensing "that USAGE of the source code, libraries and applications FOR COMMERCIAL HARDWARE OR SOFTWARE PRODUCTS IS NOT ALLOWED without prior written permission by the LinuxSampler authors."  An [ancient issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linuxsampler/+bug/252330) from 2008 appears to explain the situation, though I did not read it in sufficient detail to confirm that the situation as described is still the same.

I ended up installing it using the KX Studio PPA: I followed [their instructions*](https://kx.studio/Repositories), then performed the usual steps after installing a PPA:

```
sudo apt update;
sudo apt upgrade;
```

Then I installed the sampler package with `sudo apt install linuxsampler`.  I installed the other `linuxsampler-*` packages as well, although they shouldn't be needed for basic use of `qsampler`.

After installing those packages, `qsampler` was able to start `linuxsampler` without complaint. After downloading and decompressing the [Maestro Grand Concert](https://www.linuxsampler.org/instruments.html) instrument and doing what seemed like a rather unnecessary amount of configuration, I have an amazing piano sound that can run with considerably lower latency on my ancient laptop than the inferior sound I was getting out of `qsynth`.

*: I've refrained from including those instructions here in accordance with their request to "not copy these instructions to your own website, wiki, etc."